# Concating two list of classes

Tags: c#

I have a class that is defined like so and in the program I keep adding stuff to it

```
List<ChangesSummaryClass> allCombinationsClass = new List<ChangesSummaryClass>();
```

And I also have this class that similarly I keep adding stuff to it during the program.

```
List<ChangesSummaryClass> grandClass = new List<ChangesSummaryClass>();
```

Now I want to combine whatever object they have together on one list:

```
    List<ChangesSummaryClass> bigList = new List<ChangesSummaryClass>();
    bigList = grandClass.Concat(allCombinationsClass);
```

But I get error that can't convert source to target type.

Comment: `grandClass.Concat(allCombinationsClass).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `Concat` returns an `IEnumerable<ChangesSummaryClass>`, not a `List<ChangesSummaryClass>` as you've defined your variable.

You have two choices:

Keep `bigList` as a list

```
List<ChangesSummaryClass> bigList = new List<ChangesSummaryClass>();
bigList = grandClass.Concat(allCombinationsClass).ToList();
```

Or,

Define `bigList` as an enumerable:

```
IEnumerable<ChangesSummaryClass> bigList = new List<ChangesSummaryClass>();
bigList = grandClass.Concat(allCombinationsClass);
```

Note that defining it as an enumerable means that the concatenation and reading of the list will be done every time you iterate `bigList`. This means that any modifications done to the original lists will be reflected in `bigList` the next time you iterate it, even if you add to the list after defining `bigList` (Thanks to [Pieter Witvoet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263535/pieter-witvoet) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227014/concating-two-list-of-classes/34227060?noredirect=1#comment56198302_34227060))

Comment: You may want to point out the difference in behavior between these solutions. Specifically that modifications to the two lists are reflected in the `bigList` enumerable due to `Concat`'s 'lazy evaluation' characteristics, whereas `ToList` creates an actual new list that has no relationship with the previous two lists (other than the items they share). This could be surprising to someone not familiar with Linq.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited it into the answer

Comment: if any of these two lists I am combining, doesn't have anything in it, or even both of them have nothing in them. does this code cause any issue?

Comment: @Bohn No - both solutions will work fine in those situations (except if they are `null`, of course).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var bigList = allCombinationsClass.Union(grandClass).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Union is already distinct, so you can remove the `Distinct()` call

Comment: I want to make sure nothing get removed in between.  I am worried about "Distinct" now

Comment: Distinct only removes things from the result; the two original lists are unaffected. And as @Rob says, you could get rid of it anyway because Union does it.

Comment: yes I meant from the "result" I don't want anything removed.

Comment: Then just doing list1.Concat(list2).ToList() will work and keep things in the right order, too, I think.